# asp.net mvc entity framework with multiple databases

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4, edmx, edmx-designer

I have an ASP.Net MVC project that uses EF.  I develop this application at work computer and at my home computer.  The following is in my Web.config.  How could I change the EDMX with the proper connection string for each office?  So far, I have to drop the EDMXs and re-add them and comment out other connection strings.  Thanks.

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <!-- At Home connections -->
    <add name="App1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.App1Model.csdl|res://*/Models.App1Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.App1Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=my-pc\SqlExpress;initial catalog=App1Database;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="Service1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Service1Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Service1Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Service1Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=my-pc\SqlExpress;initial catalog=ServiceDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

    <!-- At Work connections 
    <add name="App1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.App1Model.csdl|res://*/Models.App1Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.App1Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=sqlServer1;initial catalog=App1Database;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="Service1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Service1Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Service1Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Service1Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=sqlServer2;initial catalog=ServiceDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    -->
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need multiple connection strings, but you don't have to put a switch in your code; use

```
<connectionStrings configSource="MyLocalConnectionStrings.config" />
```

[see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You'd need to maintain MyLocalConnectionStrings.config in the same dir as web.config, and have a different version for each development environment.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the schemas are the same in the two databases, it should just be a matter of replacing the connection string in web.config.  So I really don't understand what your confusion is.

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio, you can use [Config Tranforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to generate different config settings based on the mode ("Release" and "Debug" are setup by default, you can add others) selected in Configuration Manager.

Set up a transform for the connection string, then when you publish the site to Release mode, the correct connection string will be in there.

Add a mode for "Home" or something, with the appropriate connection string given your environment at home.